# How do i convert animated webp to Video?

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video, conversion, webp

**Goal :**

- convert Webp to mp4

*what i have tried :*

```
ffmpeg -i filename.webp filename.mp4
```

it's clearly not the good code. can anyone show me the way
it can be with anything like imagemagick, sharp

Comment: What error are you getting? A recent [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123376/webm-to-mp4-conversion-using-ffmpeg) indicates that some conversions are supported.

Comment: Please have have a look at the above link.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you would have to use 2 programas like imagemagick + ffmpeg

First you extract the frames using imagemagick:

```
magick input.webp frames.png
```

Then you use ffmpeg to build an mp4 video from the extracted frames:

```
ffmpeg -r 25 -i frames-%0d.png -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p "out.mp4"
```

For -r ## you specify the desired framerate...animated webp images don't have any sound but I guess you know that.

Comment: If you have an old version of imagemagick the command is `convert` instead of `magick`

Answer (score 1):

Not supported by FFmpeg yet:

> [#4907: Support decoding animated WebP images](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4907)

Comment: You copy-pasted an entire [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68369808/165358). It would have been nice to give the original author some credit.

Comment: oops, do you know any alternatives?

Comment: @harrymc it is not a solution. Just a link to a ticket. If it was a unique answer would surely give credit.

Comment: @BENNXII there are online tools availabe like https://ezgif.com/webp-to-mp4. Have you tired them?

Comment: @Anurag.k The online tool worked for me. This could be an answer post.